# coloring terminal with shell script

Tags: linux, shell, terminal

Someone can explain me why when I copy and paste the following command in the terminal it displays the colorful test correctly, but when I run it via `sh myscript.sh`  it does not display the colored text?

```
blue='\e[1;34m'
NC='\e[0m'

echo -e "${blue}Test${NC}"
```

**EDIT**

Sudo is not the problem. If I copy the above and paste directly into the terminal, everything works. If you run through file, sh myscript.sh not work

Comment: if `sh myscript.sh` works but `sudo sh myscript.sh` doesn't, then `root`'s terminal setting is probably different to your account's terminal setting.

Comment: Sudo is not the problem. If I copy the above and paste directly into the terminal, everything works. If you run through file, `sh myscript.sh` not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because `sh` isn't `bash` on your system.

```
$ file /bin/sh
/bin/sh: symbolic link to `dash'
```

Try

```
bash myscript.sh
```

Answer (score 1):

Your interactive shell seems to be GNU Bash, while `sh` is a generic POSIX shell, which actually may be `dash`, `busybox sh` or something else. The problem is that neither `-e` option for `echo` nor `\e` are POSIX-compliant.

But you can easily use `printf` instead of `echo -e` (do not forget to explicitly specify newline character `\n`) and `\033` instead of `\e`:

```
blue='\033[1;34m'
NC='\033[0m'
printf "${blue}%s${NC}\n" 'Test'
```

Or, of course, you can just use `bash` (as Elliott Frisch suggested) if you are sure that it would be available on target system.

---

Also I should point out, that what you done is not right way to run shell scripts at all. If you’re writing a standalone script, then you’d better to use hashbang and set execution bit to file.

```
$ cat myscript
#!/bin/sh

blue='\033[1;34m'
NC='\033[0m'

printf "${blue}%s${NC}\n" 'Test'

$ chmod +x myscript
$ ./myscript
```

But if you’re writing a command sequence (a macros, if you will) for interactive shell, there is `source` (or simply `.`) command:

```
$ source myscript
```

(Then all of above about POSIX-compliance does not matter of course.)

Comment: a very subjective answer and does not answer the question - the op would have had the same problem using `#!/bin/sh`.

Comment: @isedev It seems to me, I quite clearly wrote `#!/bin/bash` not `#!/bin/sh`, did not I?

Comment: yes, but the main focus of your answer was using `#!` or `source` as opposed to `(shell) script`... which IMHO has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: @isedev OK, I’ve rewritten the answer. Is it better now?